# How to open phpstorm through ubuntu terminal in Ubuntu 16.x?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, phpstorm-2016.3

What are the steps to create a launcher files to open PhpStorm in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Type in your terminal:

```
cd /var/www/MYPHPSTORMFOLDER/PhpStorm-162.2380.11/bin
```

Press Enter and type:

```
./phpstorm.sh
```

Then PHPStorm will open and go to the Launcher in left side, you can find PHPStorm icon there and just right click on that, select the option "Lock to Launcher" . FYI : First install PHPStorm through terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```
$/your phpstorm path/bin/phpstorm.sh
```

Example

```
$/opt/PhpStorm-193.6494.47/bin/phpstorm.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

> This given solution has been tested on **Ubuntu 22.10** and **PHPStorm 22.3** and also **NOTE** that I have installed **PHPStorm** from **snap** store

##### Open PHPStorm

```bash
phpstorm
```

##### Open in current directory

```bash
phpstorm .
```

##### Bonus: install PHPStorm form snap store

```bash
sudo snap install phpstorm
```

Or for `classic` version

```bash
sudo snap install phpstorm --classic
```

Or even EAP (early access program)

```
sudo snap install phpstorm --classic --edge
```